# How to use generic keys in type Script Object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
                    <div className="price font-weight-bold">₹ {car.packages?.[`intPricingPkg${carSearch.package === 0 ? 1 : carSearch.package}`]}</div>
```

Here I access the key of carSearch. which is defined in the interface like

```
packages?: {
        intPricingPkg1?: number;
        intPricingPkg2?: number;
        intPricingPkg3?: number;
        intPricingPkg4?: number;
        intPricingPkg5?: number;
        intPricingPkg6?: number;
        intPricingExtraKm?: number;
        intPricingOutstationKm?: number;
        intPricingExtraHrs?: number;
        intPricingCommission?: number;
    }
```

Now it shows the warning

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`intPricingPkg${number}`' can't be used to index type '{ intPricingPkg1?: number | undefined; intPricingPkg2?: number | undefined; intPricingPkg3?: number | undefined; intPricingPkg4?: number | undefined; intPricingPkg5?: number | undefined; ... 4 more ...; intPricingCommission?: number | undefined; }'.ts(7053)
```

Any help with getting rid of this error will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error, you explicitly tell TS what keys you're about to use:

```js
car.packages?.[`intPricingPkg${carSearch.package === 0 ? 1 : carSearch.package}` as keyof packages]
```

link to playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgA6INZwOYQM7IDeAUMmcqGAApTAKjZUbYCMA-AFzIgCuAtgCNoAblLlKNOgybYATJ278hUUeQrhJ9EI2YBmBb0EixZCbS07sAFgNLjAX2LEEAexB4wyBHCjIAvEQmaJg4+FwkampmUtoyLFwsADRBURrm0syyXLLJkeJpMZa6XLq5eerU6bHMVlxWQY72os5uHl4+AMoQPggAFv5EwQhYuFwADMhNTs4+AHTow6F4bLMA2gAG0RYyACSE3lBdPb3zIbj+fgETbMgsyFwHR1B9p4u49uvIcAQYEACeLhgQxG+AAukA

Comment: Didn't work brother

Comment: What exactly not working? do you have a TSplayground link to share?